# can anyone tell me difference between the paypal buttons

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

can anyone tell me difference between the Paypal buttons such as 
hosted button,
non-hosted button,
encrypted button,
non-encrypted button.thanks in advance

Comment: Please contact the vendor for your support options. We do not give shopping recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you want to use the hosted button solution. The differences are explained here: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ButtonMgrAPIIntro#id093VD0JE0Y4

Hosted: all parameters are encoded into an id and they are stored on paypal servers. You put the button and that's it. When you change a parameter, the id stays the same and the button is still working on all your pages.

Encrypted: values are encrypted & can't be changed by users. you must update all button codes when you change a parameter - the button-code is basically stored in encrypted form in your html.

Clear text: values (like amounts) are clear text (in your html) and can be changed by users! Flexible but you must care for fraudent behavior.

Comment: if you don't mind can you you tell me that.we can possible to override the amount dynamically by using the non hosted encrypted button

Comment: i'm not sure for the encrypted button. if you have an automated system working with the amount you should use clear text and paypals IPN to check if the right amount was transferred and not rely on the generated link (because the user can change that link).

Comment: can to go to below link .and can you tell me what can i do with that code.please.                              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721986/how-to-pass-the-user-enter-amount-value-to-the-paypal

Comment: there are some posts suggesting that it works (like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106376/dynamic-paypal-button-encryption) but it requires you to call the paypal api for the encrypted version each time. so the better solution is to use IPN, where above all, you can be sure that you also only process payments which are finished.

Comment: did you gone through my code .Hi am having an issue with a website I am writing in php.I am trying to get Paypal to accept a user enter amount.but it not accepting while redirecting to paypal the amount is blank.is this possible or not.

Comment: so basically you want the user to enter an amount on your page, encrypt it and then redirect to paypal? that would make no sense, since the user has entered the amount anyway you can easily use the non-encrypted version. no additional security through encrypting it.

Comment: if i use the non encrypted button my paypal id is shown to them.how to hide that you know how

Comment: well if i remember correctly this will be shown anyway as recipient of a payment as soon as you reach the pay step. the user must know to where his money goes after all.

Comment: imagine if user friend is near with him.user open the paypal button page unfortunately user went without close that page.his friend can modify the email id to his mail id .when user came and click the pay button the payment done to the friend account .not to the seller account

Comment: please tell me some suggestion

Comment: well even IF this scanario would appy, the user has to login on paypal himself and make the payment. if someone changed the mail before then a) a session should run out anyway and b) using paypal IPNs you can and should add the amount to the user account identified by the paypal mail address. i don't have a suggestion for the other solution, maybe paypal support can help.